# Timeless and updated function make feature layer

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, feature-layer

I'm doing an interface using ArcGIS 10.2, so I need my operations are automatically and timeless. So I'm using Python scripts because I can't use directly functions such as "MakeFeatureLayer". I also need that when I run my script, it updates data, so I think that I need to delete before my layers, so I used this code, but it can't delete, gives error, and if I don't delete it says that layer exists..

```
lyr60=r"F:ArcGis\Trab\Model\Lin_trocos.shp\tr_cri_60"

arcpy.Delete_management(lyr60) 
lyr60=arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(r"F:ArcGIS\Trab\Model\Lin_trocos.shp", "tr_cri_60")   

cri_60=[2,4,8,10] #List of index that I want display on map

cri_60_str = ','.join(str(val) for val in cri_60)
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("tr_cri_60", "NEW_SELECTION", '"FID" IN ({})'.format(cri_60_str))
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Please format your code by highlighting it and using the format (**`{}`**) button, and as per "no chit chat" in the [Tour] can you not include the unnecessary "Thanks" in your posts, please?

Answer (score 1):

You want to check if your feature layer "tr_cri_60" exists first, and if it does remove it.  This will remove the feature layer, not the underlying data.  Once the feature layer is gone (if necessary) you can then create it fresh, and run your selection.

```
shpfile = r"F:ArcGis\Trab\Model\Lin_trocos.shp"

if arcpy.Exists("tr_cri_60"):
    arcpy.Delete_management("tr_cri_60") 

lyr60 = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(shpfile, "tr_cri_60")   

cri_60 = [2,4,8,10] #List of index that I want display on map
cri_60_str = ','.join(str(val) for val in cri_60)

arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(lyr60, "NEW_SELECTION", '"FID" IN ({})'.format(cri_60_str))
```

Alternatively I'd suggest using `layer.setSelectionSet()` to select based on `FID` or `ObjectID` as this can run quicker than an `arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute()`.  `layer.setSelectionSet()` directly selects a list of IDs - it won't work on other attribute types.

```
shpfile = r"F:ArcGis\Trab\Model\Lin_trocos.shp"

if arcpy.Exists("tr_cri_60"):
    arcpy.Delete_management("tr_cri_60") 

arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(shpfile, "tr_cri_60")   

cri_60 = [2,4,8,10] #List of index that I want display on map
lyr60 = arcpy.mapping.Layer("tr_cri_60")

lyr60.setSelectionSet("NEW", cri_60)
```

Comment: the first part of your answer works, but the second don't works ( lyr60.setSelectionSet("NEW", cri_60) ).
But when I try to apply this to CrateTable function it gives me an error: "000601 : Cannot delete <value>. May be locked by another application."

Comment: @S.Rai Your code snippet didn't mention anything about Create Table - I think this is a new question.

Comment: @S.Rai Regarding the `lyr60.setSelectionSet()` not working, what error do you get?  The code snippet above worked fine for me when I test it.  Please be aware these are two separate options for the same part of code, not used together.